# Pandas dataframes merge repeats values to get aligned

Tags: python, sql, database, pandas, dataframe

Here is the link to original dataset source:
[dataset for capacity](http://data.bayanat.ae/en_GB/dataset/mosques-by-capacity-and-emirate/resource/5cc69203-3419-429e-b917-7dc13e917419) and [dataset for type](http://data.bayanat.ae/en_GB/dataset/mosques-by-type-and-emirate/resource/5fa5479f-4580-4e1f-b343-73a8e1c270c0)

or modified version [dataset modified1](https://justpaste.it/edit/26958949/a89cf081da03ba29) and [dataset modified2](https://justpaste.it/edit/26970805/9d75c79a18f2e497)

I have 2 dataframes to merge:

```
  first_df=pd.DataFrame([['2001','Abu Dhabi','100-','462'],['2001','Abu Dhabi','100','44'],['2001','Abu Dhabi','200','462'],['2001','Dubai','100-','40'],['2001','Dubai','100','30'],['2001','Dubai','200','51'],['2002','Abu Dhabi','100-','300'],['2002','Abu Dhabi','100','220'],['2002','Abu Dhabi','200','56'],['2002','Dubai','100-','55'],['2002','Dubai','100','67'],['2002','Dubai','200','89']],columns=['Year','Emirate','Capacity','Number'])

  second_df=pd.DataFrame([['2001','Abu Dhabi','Performed','45'],['2001','Abu Dhabi','Not Performed','76'],['2001','Dubai','Performed','90'],['2001','Dubai','Not Performed','50'],['2002','Abu Dhabi','Performed','78'],['2002','Abu Dhabi','Not Performed','45'],['2002','Dubai','Performed','76'],['2002','Dubai','Not Performed','58']],columns=['Year','Emirate','Type','Value'])
```

so i've set multiIndex for both dataframes:

```
first=first_df.set_index(['Year','Emirate'])
second=second_df.set_index(['Year','Emirate'])
```

and merged:

```
merged=first.merge(second,how='outer',right_index=True,left_index=True)
```

with the following result:

## Merged

`| Year , Emirate        | Capacity   |   count | friday        |   count |
|:----------------------|:-----------|--------:|:--------------|--------:|
| ('2001', 'Abu Dhabi') | 100-       |     462 | Performed     |      45 |
| ('2001', 'Abu Dhabi') | 100-       |     462 | Not Performed |      76 |
| ('2001', 'Abu Dhabi') | 100        |      44 | Performed     |      45 |
| ('2001', 'Abu Dhabi') | 100        |      44 | Not Performed |      76 |
| ('2001', 'Abu Dhabi') | 200        |     657 | Performed     |      45 |
| ('2001', 'Abu Dhabi') | 200        |     657 | Not Performed |      76 |
| ('2001', 'Dubai')     | 100-       |      40 | Performed     |      90 |
| ('2001', 'Dubai')     | 100-       |      40 | Not Performed |      50 |
| ('2001', 'Dubai')     | 100        |      30 | Performed     |      90 |
| ('2001', 'Dubai')     | 100        |      30 | Not Performed |      50 |
| ('2001', 'Dubai')     | 200        |      51 | Performed     |      90 |
| ('2001', 'Dubai')     | 200        |      51 | Not Performed |      50 |
| ('2002', 'Abu Dhabi') | 100-       |     300 | Performed     |      78 |
| ('2002', 'Abu Dhabi') | 100-       |     300 | Not Performed |      45 |
| ('2002', 'Abu Dhabi') | 100        |     220 | Performed     |      78 |
| ('2002', 'Abu Dhabi') | 100        |     220 | Not Performed |      45 |
| ('2002', 'Abu Dhabi') | 200        |      56 | Performed     |      78 |
| ('2002', 'Abu Dhabi') | 200        |      56 | Not Performed |      45 |
| ('2002', 'Dubai')     | 100-       |      55 | Performed     |      76 |
| ('2002', 'Dubai')     | 100-       |      55 | Not Performed |      58 |
| ('2002', 'Dubai')     | 100        |      67 | Performed     |      76 |
| ('2002', 'Dubai')     | 100        |      67 | Not Performed |      58 |
| ('2002', 'Dubai')     | 200        |      89 | Performed     |      76 |
| ('2002', 'Dubai')     | 200        |      89 | Not Performed |      58 |`

and tried to concat with the following result:

```
joined=pd.concat([first,second])
```

## JOINED

`| Year , Emirate        | Capacity   |   Number | Type          |   Value |
|:----------------------|:-----------|---------:|:--------------|--------:|
| ('2001', 'Abu Dhabi') | 100-       |      462 | nan           |     nan |
| ('2001', 'Abu Dhabi') | 100        |       44 | nan           |     nan |
| ('2001', 'Abu Dhabi') | 200        |      657 | nan           |     nan |
| ('2001', 'Dubai')     | 100-       |       40 | nan           |     nan |
| ('2001', 'Dubai')     | 100        |       30 | nan           |     nan |
| ('2001', 'Dubai')     | 200        |       51 | nan           |     nan |
| ('2002', 'Abu Dhabi') | 100-       |      300 | nan           |     nan |
| ('2002', 'Abu Dhabi') | 100        |      220 | nan           |     nan |
| ('2002', 'Abu Dhabi') | 200        |       56 | nan           |     nan |
| ('2002', 'Dubai')     | 100-       |       55 | nan           |     nan |
| ('2002', 'Dubai')     | 100        |       67 | nan           |     nan |
| ('2002', 'Dubai')     | 200        |       89 | nan           |     nan |
| ('2001', 'Abu Dhabi') | nan        |      nan | Performed     |      45 |
| ('2001', 'Abu Dhabi') | nan        |      nan | Not Performed |      76 |
| ('2001', 'Dubai')     | nan        |      nan | Performed     |      90 |
| ('2001', 'Dubai')     | nan        |      nan | Not Performed |      50 |
| ('2002', 'Abu Dhabi') | nan        |      nan | Performed     |      78 |
| ('2002', 'Abu Dhabi') | nan        |      nan | Not Performed |      45 |
| ('2002', 'Dubai')     | nan        |      nan | Performed     |      76 |
| ('2002', 'Dubai')     | nan        |      nan | Not Performed |      58 |`

so two dataframes joined together not supposed to have duplicates(like first merged) or shift down (like concat variant). 
What can be a solution to make 2 dataframes to align nicely?

Here is how the desired output may look like:

`|    |   Year | Emirate   | Capacity   |   Number | Type          |   Value |
|---:|-------:|:----------|:-----------|---------:|:--------------|--------:|
|  0 |        |           | 100-       |      462 | Performed     |      45 |
|  1 |        | Abu Dhabi | 100        |       44 | Not Performed |      76 |
|  2 |        |           | 200        |      657 | NaN           |     nan |
|  3 |   2001 |           | 100-       |       40 | Performed     |      90 |
|  4 |        | Dubai     | 100        |       30 | Not Performed |      50 |
|  5 |        |           | 200        |       51 | NaN           |     nan |
|  6 |        |           | 100-       |      300 | Performed     |      78 |
|  7 |        | Abu Dhabi | 100        |      220 | Not Performed |      45 |
|  8 |   2002 |           | 200        |       56 | NaN           |     nan |
|  9 |        |           | 100-       |       55 | Performed     |      76 |
| 10 |        | Dubai     | 100        |       67 | Not Performed |      58 |
| 11 |        |           | 200        |       89 | NaN           |     nan |`

```
enter code here
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Which rows do you consider as duplicate in your merged dataframe?

Comment: I did merged1=first.merge(second,how='inner',right_index=True,left_index=True).drop_duplicates() and the row counts where same. As already commented, please all "duplicates" to the questions

Comment: @Erfan yes, i've added how expected output can be

Comment: @Ravi yes, did try drop_duplicates() before but didnt resulted in nice alignment

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem here, you data is in such a way that it results in a cross join when you are joining on `['year','Emirate']`. e,g  2001 Abu Dhabi joined with 2001 Abu Dhabi in both data frames for "performed and Not performed". Basically this is m x n relation joining datasets. Unless you specify a primary key which can identify each row uniquely you would end up with the same results.

Comment: Yeah, it may look like a good idea. was using it in sql. Can you specify how primary key  works with pandas? never come across it, didnt find much after googling it...

Comment: Index in pandas works like primary key, and here you have used 2 columns which is similar to composite key (as in sql) however, even you composite key is not able to identify a unique row. For e.g. in your df, if you search on "2001 Abu Dhabi" you would get 3 rows instead of one unique

Comment: Well, the thing is that all the rows are unique on its own - there is no rows that are absolutely identical - at least on of the values in a row is different from another row. And that is why  certain values get repeated so that it bring a unique match ultimately.

Comment: is there any solution that you are suggesting in particularly within pandas library to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

I assumed your data is not correct yet, since your expected output is possible, but not with your logic right now.

Your are missing a third `key column` in `second_df` which is `capacity`. If we add this column and perform a `left merge`, we can achieve your expected output.

btw, we dont need to set the columns as index, so the solution looks like this.

```
# Clean up and create correct dataframes
first_df=pd.DataFrame([['2001','Abu Dhabi','100-','462'],
                       ['2001','Abu Dhabi','100','44'],
                       ['2001','Abu Dhabi','200','657'],
                       ['2001','Dubai','100-','40'],
                       ['2001','Dubai','100','30'],
                       ['2001','Dubai','200','51'],
                       ['2002','Abu Dhabi','100-','300'],
                       ['2002','Abu Dhabi','100','220'],
                       ['2002','Abu Dhabi','200','56'],
                       ['2002','Dubai','100-','55'],
                       ['2002','Dubai','100','67'],
                       ['2002','Dubai','200','89']],columns=['Year','Emirate','Capacity','Number'])
second_df=pd.DataFrame([['2001','Abu Dhabi','100-','Performed','45'],
                        ['2001','Abu Dhabi','100','Not Performed','76'],
                        ['2001','Abu Dhabi','','',''],
                        ['2001','Dubai','100-','Performed','90'],
                        ['2001','Dubai','100','Not Performed','50'],
                        ['2001','Dubai','','',''],
                        ['2002','Abu Dhabi','100-','Performed','78'],
                        ['2002','Abu Dhabi','100','Not Performed','45'],
                        ['2002','Abu Dhabi','', '', ''],
                        ['2002','Dubai','100-','Performed','76'],
                        ['2002','Dubai','100','Not Performed','58'],
                        ['2002','Dubai', '', '', '']],columns=['Year','Emirate','Capacity','Type','Value'])

# Perform a left merge to get correct output
merged=first_df.merge(second_df,how='left',on=['Year', 'Emirate', 'Capacity'])
```

**Output**

```
    Year    Emirate     Capacity    Number  Type            Value
0   2001    Abu Dhabi   100-        462     Performed       45
1   2001    Abu Dhabi   100         44      Not Performed   76
2   2001    Abu Dhabi   200         657     NaN             NaN
3   2001    Dubai       100-        40      Performed       90
4   2001    Dubai       100         30      Not Performed   50
5   2001    Dubai       200         51      NaN             NaN
6   2002    Abu Dhabi   100-        300     Performed       78
7   2002    Abu Dhabi   100         220     Not Performed   45
8   2002    Abu Dhabi   200         56      NaN             NaN
9   2002    Dubai       100-        55      Performed       76
10  2002    Dubai       100         67      Not Performed   58
11  2002    Dubai       200         89      NaN             NaN
```

Comment: It is interesting solution. the output looks good. My concern is that original data is much reacher with types of capacities - i mean that in first dataset there are 8 capacities: like: 100-,100,200,400,600,800,1000,1000+ and for both datasets there are 7 states: Dubai, Abu Dhabi, Sharjah etc...

Comment: i will try to add link to the file